# Tkinter Canvas Rectangle Grid Draw Binding

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am creating a grid of 30x30 canvas rectangles. I am trying to bind clicks on these rectangles. I am running a loop like this:

```
for x in range(0, wid, 30):
    for y in range(0, leng, 30):
        rectangle = drawCanv.create_rectangle(x, y, x+30, y+30, outline='black')  
        drawCanv.tag_bind(rectangle, func=chooseImg(impFiles=importFiles, impsDirs=imports))
```

When I call this looop, the buttons draw, but the `chooseImg` function also executes on its own. Even though I did not click it. Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: No. That is talking about the Button() method. Not canvas rectangle.

Comment: @MrTim *Button or event* its the same mechanic. Read the Q&A of this thread.

Comment: try ```func=lambda: chooseImg(impFiles=importFiles, impsDirs=imports))```

Comment: should have thought of that thanks.